# IF value is in list set value in next column NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge SQL table and need to filter several columns (called `Field`) if they are in this list:

```
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE
```

If this is the case, set respective `value` column to NULL.

Let me give you an example table:

```
Field1  Value1  Field2  Value2 ...... Field10  Value10
  AAA     9A      AAA     9A            CCC       World    
  BBB     1       KKK     0    
  ZZZ     9       AAA     9A            CCC       42      
  CCC     7
  LLL     9       AAA     3             III       98     
  KKK     3       AAA     4    
  DDD     100     AAA     Hello         CCC       6
```

Not all Field Value combinations are filled up until `Value10`. However every column that is named `FieldXX` must be checked for the list entries. If a cell is equal to a list entry the respective value field should be set NULL. Otherwise the value field remains untouched.

I struggle to figure out the correct `CASE` statement for this specific issue. I tried the following code:

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN Field* = AAA or BBB or CCC or DDD or EEE 
                     THEN Value* = 0
                  ELSE Value* = Value*
             END AS bit)
FROM dbo.Log
```

But this query totally fails and it might not be for specific field-value pairs.

**Expected Output**

```
Field1  Value1  Field2  Value2 ...... Field10  Value10
  AAA     0       AAA     0            CCC       0    
  BBB     0       KKK     0    
  ZZZ     9       AAA     0            CCC       0      
  CCC     0
  LLL     9       AAA     0            III       98     
  KKK     3       AAA     0    
  DDD     0       AAA     0            CCC       0
```

Table name is `dbo.Log`.

Comment: Is your expected output meant to be same table updated or a new table?

Comment: @DKyleo Yeah, new table would be awesome using ```create```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the wildcard you're trying to use for your `CASE WHEN` isn't a valid way of using it.

You can use variables to create a SQL string that you can then copy and execute - this way, if you need to increase the number of fields you're checking, you only have to change one part of your code :)

The code below creates the SQL string then prints it out in the console window:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ';
WHILE @cnt <= 10
BEGIN 
DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Field' + CAST(@cnt AS varchar(max))
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Value' + CAST(@cnt AS varchar(max))
SET @sql = @sql + @COLUMN + ', CASE WHEN ' + @COLUMN + '= ''AAA'' OR '  + @COLUMN + '= ''BBB'' OR ' + @COLUMN + '= ''CCC'' OR ' + @COLUMN + '= ''DDD'' OR ' + @COLUMN + '= ''EEE'' THEN 0 ELSE ' + @VALUE + ' END AS ' + @VALUE;
IF @cnt != 10 
(SELECT @sql = @sql + ',')
SET @cnt = @cnt +1
END

SET @sql = @sql + ' INTO [dbo].[LogFilter] FROM [dbo].[Log]';
PRINT @sql;
```

This code below is what is printed out (I have styled it so you can easily read it and truncated it so it doesn't take up the whole screen) :)

```
SELECT 
  Field1, 
  CASE WHEN Field1= 'AAA' OR Field1= 'BBB' OR Field1= 'CCC' OR Field1= 'DDD' OR Field1= 'EEE'
  THEN 0 ELSE Value1 END AS Value1,
  Field2, 
  CASE WHEN Field2= 'AAA' OR Field2= 'BBB' OR Field2= 'CCC' OR Field2= 'DDD' OR Field2= 'EEE' 
  THEN 0 ELSE Value2 END AS Value2,
  Field3, 
  CASE WHEN Field3= 'AAA' OR Field3= 'BBB' OR Field3= 'CCC' OR Field3= 'DDD' OR Field3= 'EEE' 
  THEN 0 ELSE Value3 END AS Value3, 
  ...
  INTO [dbo].[LogFilter] FROM [dbo].[Log]
```

This `SELECT INTO` statement above places your filtered information into a brand new table :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to update ValueX columns based on FieldX data.
In that case you need to write Case condition for every column.

You can directly write 10 Case conditions like below

```
UPDATE A_LOG 
SET VALUE1 = CASE WHEN FIELD1 IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE' ) THEN 0 ELSE VALUE1 END,
VALUE2 = CASE WHEN FIELD2 IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE' ) THEN 0 ELSE VALUE2 END,
VALUE3 = CASE WHEN FIELD3 IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE' ) THEN 0 ELSE VALUE3 END
.
.
VALUE10 = CASE WHEN FIELD10 IN ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE' ) THEN 0 ELSE VALUE10 END
```

Or you can generate Update statement with Dynamic query like below

```
DECLARE @IN VARCHAR(100)=' IN (''AAA'',''BBB'',''CCC'',''DDD'',''EEE'' )'
, @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) =  'UPDATE A_LOG SET '

SELECT @SQL = @SQL+  VAL FROM 
(
SELECT    COLUMN_NAME + ' = CASE WHEN FIELD'+ REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'VALUE','')
+ @IN+ ' THEN 0 ELSE '+ COLUMN_NAME + ' END,
' VAL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'LOG'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'VALUE%'
)A

SELECT @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL,1,LEN(@SQL)-3)
SELECT @SQL
```

That will give you update statement for every column with a case condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Declare @Table Table(Field1 varchar(10), Value1 varchar(10),  Field2 varchar(10),  Value2 varchar(10) ,Field10 varchar(10) , Value10 varchar(10))
    Declare @NewTable Table(Field1 varchar(10), Value1 varchar(10),  Field2 varchar(10),  Value2 varchar(10) ,Field10 varchar(10) , Value10 varchar(10))

    insert into @Table
    SELECT 'AAA','9A','AAA','9A','CCC','World' Union All
    SELECT 'BBB','1','KKK','0',NULL,NULL    Union All
    SELECT 'ZZZ','9','AAA','9A','CCC','42'   Union All    
    SELECT 'CCC','7',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL Union All
    SELECT 'LLL','9','AAA','3','III','98' Union All
    SELECT 'KKK','3','AAA','4',NULL,NULL    Union All
    SELECT 'DDD','100','AAA','Hello','CCC','6' 


    INSERT into @NewTable
    Select Field1,CASE WHEN Field1 in ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE') THEN 0 else Value1 end As Value1
        ,Field2,CASE WHEN Field2 in ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE') THEN 0 else Value2 end As Value2
        ,Field10,CASE WHEN Field10 in ('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE') THEN 0 else Value10 end As Value10
    from @Table 

    Select * from @NewTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The Case statement wouldn't work in the way that you've written. You need to individually compare the values in each Field and set the value of 'Value' column.

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN Field1 = AAA or BBB or CCC or DDD or EEE 
                     THEN Value1 = 0                     
                  ELSE Value1
             END AS bit) Value1,
        CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN Field2 = AAA or BBB or CCC or DDD or EEE 
                     THEN Value2 = 0                     
                  ELSE Value2
             END AS bit) Value2,
        .    
        .
        .
        .
        <need to write separate case statement for each column which is to be compared>
FROM dbo.Log
```